# Does Lie Bracket take basis changes into account?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Let, we have a 2d space with metric $g_{xx} = y^2$, $g_{yy} = 1$, diagonal metric. Let $u = e_x$, $v = e_y$. So, vector components are constant (1), but the basis $e_x$ is not.
Will that be considered when calculating the Lie Bracket? More specically, does u(v) or v(u) consider basis changes?

Answer (score 1):

The Lie bracket of two vector fields is a vector field whose components depend on the choice of basis vectors. So if you change coordinate systems and therefore change the basis vectors for every tangent space on your manifold, the components of the Lie bracket will change exactly as the components of a tensor.

However, I think the OP is referring to a change in basis vectors as we move over and around the manifold. In this case the answer is no. The Lie bracket does not account for how basis vectors might change from one point on a manifold to another. The reason being that the definition of the Lie bracket (or in general the Lie derivative) does not require the specification of a [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics)). A connection is required however to define the covariant derivative.

In the OP's example, we work on a 2D manifold with coordinates $x$ and $y$, coordinate basis vectors $e_x$ and $e_y$, and metric components $g_{\alpha\beta} = \text{diag}(y^2, 1)$. The norm of $e_x$ changes as we move in the $y$-direction. Nonetheless, the Lie bracket of $u=e_x$ and $v=e_y$ (or the Lie derivative of $v$ along $u$) is

$$\mathcal{L}_u v = [u, v] = (u^\alpha \partial_\alpha v^\beta-v^\alpha\partial_\alpha u^\beta)e_\beta = 0$$

as $u^\alpha = (1, 0)$ and $v^\alpha = (0, 1)$. If we've established a connection on the manifold then we can equivalently write the Lie bracket using the covariant derivative

$$\mathcal{L}_u v = [u, v] = (u^\alpha \nabla_\alpha v^\beta-v^\alpha\nabla_\alpha u^\beta)e_\beta$$

As opposed to the expression in terms of partial derivatives, each term here is a proper tensor. Indeed by expanding the covariant derivatives, you'll see the Christoffel symbols (which dictate the connection) cancel, leaving only the partial derivatives behind.